# How to remove temp files with a command other then “apt-get autoremove” in Kali Linux?

Tags: linux, debian, filesystems

I have Kali Linux OS running on Debian 4.18.0.

The system crashed and tells me that:

> "Your cache memory full, please remove cache and temp files".

I want to know that if there is a command other than:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

To remove cache temp files from the system?

Comment: Just curious - why do you want to know this? What is wrong with `sudo apt-get autoremove`?

Comment: I don't believe "autoremove" has anything to do with cache or temp files. It uninstalls packages that were automatically installed, but are no longer required.

Answer (score 1):

1. Clear the cache file:

   ```
   sudo apt-get clean
   ```
2. Clear the cache file automatically:

   ```
   sudo apt-get autoclean
   ```